# BeautifulSoup - Python - Find the key from HTML

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have been practicing with bs4 and Python and now I have been stucked.

My plan is to do a If - Else state where I wanted to do similar like

```
If(I find a value inside this html)
   Do This method
Else: 
   Do something else
```

and I have scraped up a html I found randomly which looks like -

```
<div class="Talkinghand" data-backing="ShowingHide" data-key="123456" data-theme="$MemeTheme" style=""></div>
```

and what I have done so far is that:

```
s = requests.Session()
    Url = 'www.myhtml.com' #Just took a random page which I don't feel to insert
    r = s.get(Url)
    soup = soup(r, "lxml")
    findKey = soup.find(('div', {'class': 'Talkinghand'})['data-key'])
    print(findKey)
```

but no luck. Gives me error and

> TypeError: object of type 'Response' has no len()

Once I find or print out the key. I wanted to do a if else statement where it also says:

If(there is a value inside that data-key) 
 ...

Comment: What is `s` in `s.get`?

Comment: Oh sorry, It is (s = requests.Session())

Comment: `r` is a Response object. Does `soup(r.content, 'lxml')` fix for you

Comment: Oh. Yes I think so but then im getting ```findKey = soup.find(('div', {'class': 'Talkinghand'})['data-key'])
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str```

Comment: You have some unnecessary parenthesis. `soup.find('div', {'class': 'Talkinghand'})['data-key']`

Comment: @piroot I dont really understand what you mean by that

----- Psidom Oh, How can I improve that? Oh I removed the () but then im getting that KeyError: 'data-key'

Comment: Have you printed `soup.find('div', {'class': 'Talkinghand'})`? Does it contain a `data-key` attribute?

Comment: Yes. it does give me a <div class="Talkinghand" data-backing="ShowingHide" data-key="123456"></div>

Comment: Oh, I had to do soup.find('div', {'class': 'Talkinghand'})['data-key'] but also getting ```AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find_all'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?```

Comment: The error seems mysterious to me. I didn't see where you use `find_all`, maybe there's some code you didn't share. But whenever you use `find_all` make sure you use a for loop to extract the content.

Comment: I do have find_all but thats below the code. Like far away from each other? Why would that matter in that case? :O Oh you are right, This is a error from another line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To display the `data-key` attribute from inside the `<div>` tag, you can do the following:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '<div class="Talkinghand" data-backing="ShowingHide" data-key="123456" data-theme="$MemeTheme" style=""></div>'
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

print soup.div['data-key']
```

This would print:

```
123456
```

You would need to pass `r.content` to your `soup` call.

Your script had an extra `(` and `)`, so the following would also work:

```
findKey = soup.find('div', {'class': 'Talkinghand'})['data-key']
print findKey
```

Comment: Correct, Thank you so much! This really helped me :)